# Should I clone a node library inside node_modules to modify it?

Tags: git, node.js, clone, require, npm

I'm using [Poet](https://github.com/jsantell/poet) for a blogging/static site generator engine and it's great.

It is currently a dependency listed in my packages.json, so I simply `npm install` it and `require` it in my express app.

However, I'd like to change one behavior in the library (especifically the way a "post.preview" is constructed, which right now simply gets the first line, and I'd like to perhaps be able to configure a number of lines for each post).

To do that, I'm considering cloning the repo and making the change.

But I'm wondering if I should:

- Clone it directly to my blog/node_modules/poet and `require` it as usual or,
- Clone it to a different folder and `require` it from a different path.

Keep in mind that I'd like to publish soon to Heroku or Nodejitsu.

What are your thoughts on that?

**UPDATE**: I had a few problems having a git repo with the cloned lib under my git repo. It somehow added the whole folder as a file. I promptly removed '.git' from the lib folder and everything went back to normal... I don't know the cause of this behavior!

Comment: (on the UPDATE): Edit `.gitignore` add this line `/lib/<myRepo>` You shouldn't have problems after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, a good practice is to clone and keep this repository into the folder `/lib`. Once you feel you are done with your changes, push them into your version, and make the right references to your copy in the `package.json` file.

Now, if you think your changes could be introduced into the module, make the pull request.

My two cents.

Comment: Yep, it seems npm complains about having strange things in node_modules. I have it under a different folder right now... But I updated the question with a new git trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's any guidelines on this, but personally I would fork poet and make the change, and add that as an external repository for your application in a different directory from node_modules. I just like to keep node_modules managed by npm.

My goal would be able to deploy using a git pull + npm install, while being able to easily continue merging updates from the poet mainline.

Comment: Noted. I'll wait for more opinions, though.